# SingleOrDefaultAsync: what does it actually mean?

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

As someone who deals with *'old'* C# and now getting up to speed as I move to ASP.NET, I'm wondering if anybody could help me with this simple example. 
The built in wizard generates code like this:

```
var product = await _context.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ProductId == id);
```

now, what do I get by the lamba expression `m => m.ProductId == id`? why can't it just be:

```
var product = await _context.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m.ProductId);
```

I'm trying to read the documentation but it only adds to my confusion. it documents the query is:

```
public static Task<TSource> SingleOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source
)
```

so... what does it mean that it returns a Task? is that a generic? what is the `<TSource>` doing there 3 times?

any reference to general reading that would clarify this will be highly appreciated... are these what's called expression trees? is this Linc...? where would i start? etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Your `var product = ...` lines are the same. I think you meant to post something else.

Comment: This is going to get very, very broad. I'd suggest you start by reading up on .NET asynchronous calls (Task object) and Lambda expressions. Also TSource is generic type, in a generic function.

Comment: The signature of `SingleOrDefaultAsync` that you posted is not the same method seen in your `var product = ...` line because the one your code is using accepts a `Func<TSource,Boolean>` parameter in addition to `this IQueryable<TSource>`.

Comment: Thanks all. yes i edited the 2nd line. ok, I understand that this is an extension method to IQuerytable but... i don't even know where to start my readings... I'll start with the Task object. thanks again

Comment: I'd recommend you to read articles on learn.microsoft.com, there are guides basicly about everything you need to get answers to all your questions about [Lambda's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions), [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq), [Expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/index), ...

Comment: ... [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index) and [many more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/index)

Answer (score 2):

So the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleordefaultasync(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync%60%601%28System.Linq.IQueryable%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,System.Boolean%7D%7D%29) for the correct overload of `SingleOrDefaultAsync` has the signature as:

```
public static Task<TSource> SingleOrDefaultAsync<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate
)
```

This is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) as indicated by the `this` preceding the first parameter. An extension method is a static method that is used (syntactically) as if it is a member method.

So, the first parameter `source` will be `_context.Products`.

The second parameter is an `Expression<Func<>>` which means the compiler will convert the [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) passed in into an [`Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions?view=netframework-4.7) data structure representing the code. A lambda expression is used to allow you to specify any desired conditions for the query being executed e.g. you could have `m => m.ProductId == id && m.Active` to exclude inactivated products.

So, your second parameter `predicate` will be `m => m.ProductId == id` as an `Expression` tree, which the method can convert to SQL and send to the database.

Finally, the return type of [`Task<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=netframework-4.7) indicates the method will be executed [asynchronously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap?view=netframework-4.7) and you will immediately get a `Task` object which you can use to get the actual result once it is available.

Calling [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index) on the result causes this method to be paused in execution, control to return to the caller (which also gets a `Task` object), and this method to be resumed once the `Task` completes.

Comment: excellent! Thanks NetMage. that's exactly what i needed. the Expression data structure is what i didn't get. It's all clear now. Thanks again!